# Find and insert in Complex JSON object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an object like below

```
interface  Employee {
id: number;
name: string;
parentid: number;
level: string;
children?: Employee[];
}

const Data: Employee[] = [
{
id:1,  name: 'name1', parentid:0, level: 'L1',
children: [
  { id: 2, name: 'name2', parentid:1, level: 'L2'},
  { id: 3, name: 'name3', parentid:1, level: 'L2',
children: [
  {id: 4, name: 'name4', parentid:3, level: 'L3'}
]}
]
}
];
```

### here children parentid is mapped into parentdata 'id'.

if i have new data with [id=5, name:'name5', parentid=0 and Level='L1'] and its children data [id=6, name='name6']. we need to check the if the given id=5 is exist with L1. if not then add like below

```
[
{
id:1,  name: 'name1', parentid:0, level: 'L1',
children: [
  { id: 2, name: 'name2', parentid:1, level: 'L2'},
  { id: 3, name: 'name3', parentid:1, level: 'L2',
children: [
  {id: 4, name: 'name4', parentid:3, level: 'L3'}
]}
]
},
{
id:5,  name: 'name5', parentid:0, level: 'L1',
children: [
  { id: 6, name: 'name6', parentid:5, level: 'L2'}
]  
}
];
```

if i have new data with id:7, name:'name7', parentid=3  then it has to find with id 3 and add it like below

```
[
{
id:1,  name: 'name1', parentid:0, level: 'L1',
children: [
  { id: 2, name: 'name2', parentid:1, level: 'L2'},
  { id: 3, name: 'name3', parentid:1, level: 'L2',
children: [
  {id: 4, name: 'name4', parentid:3, level: 'L3'},
  {id: 7, name: 'name7', parentid:3, level: 'L3'}
]}
]
},
{
id:5,  name: 'name5', parentid:0, level: 'L1',
children: [
  { id: 6, name: 'name6', parentid:5, level: 'L2'}
]  
}
];
```

please guide me

Comment: Can different children have same parentid?

Comment: thanks for your reply sivakumar. nope.

Comment: is the answer given helped?

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply. i tried your solution. when i try to add new children under a children, instead of adding as children its adds as new row. sorry am not able to add image for your reference. please give me a mail id i will forward the image

Answer (score 2):

You need to recursively find the parent and if it has children then push the data to children array that you want.

In the below code snippet, try to comment or uncomment different `findParent` calls and console logs

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'name1',
  parentid: 0,
  level: 'L1',
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'name2',
      parentid: 1,
      level: 'L2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'name3',
      parentid: 1,
      level: 'L2',
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'name4',
        parentid: 3,
        level: 'L3'
      }]
    }
  ]
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: 'name5',
  parentid: 0,
  level: 'L1',
  children: [{
    id: 6,
    name: 'name6',
    parentid: 5,
    level: 'L2'
  }]
}];

const insertData = {
  id: 7,
  name: 'name7',
  parentid: 3,
  level: 'L3'
};
const insertDataTwo = {
  id: 10,
  name: 'name7',
  parentid: 5,
  level: 'L3'
};

function findParent(d, ind) {
  d.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === ind.parentid) {
      if (item.children) {
        item.children = [...item.children, ind]
      } else {
        item['children'] = [ind];
      }
    } else {
      if (item.children) {
        findParent(item.children, ind);
      }
    }
  });
}

//findParent(data, insertData);

//console.log(data);

findParent(data, insertDataTwo);

console.log(data);
```